# JQuery prepend function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi all probably pretty easy question here.

I'm prepending `<td>` to a table row and I want to put a selectors value inside.

HTML :

```
<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='text1'>this is the text</div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$('#tablediv tr:eq(3)').prepend('<td></td>');
```

I want to add div value inside the created td:

```
$('#tablediv tr:eq(3)').prepend('<td>$text1</td>').html(); this does not work.
```

Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: mistake line I have: ('#fieldset_Q2 tr:eq(3)').prepend('<td></td>'); and I want to have $('#fieldset_Q9 td:eq(3)').prepend($("tdText1").html());

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with .html();

Comment: Cant you just use $(#'text1').replaceWith('Your content')?   im not excellent with jquery but my guess is there will be a million ways to do this.

Comment: I have a table and I prepend a cell like this: $('#tablediv tr:eq(3)').prepend('<td></td>');  how to put the value of this #text1 inside this this td on the same row as I do not want many lines of code. I'm just trying to reduce number of lines, because I can do it other ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert the value of the div's text, use `.text()`. Then place that in your `<td>`

```
$('#tablediv tr:eq(3)').prepend('<td>'+$('#text1').text()+'</td>');
```

Comment: This works, but another quick question how to add a column span to this?

Comment: Use `.prepend('<td colspan="2"'>`)` but it depends on how you think the "column span" would work whether this would suffice.   Most likely you'll need to add new cells to all the other rows as well (which can be done easily enough).

Comment: @ZygimantasKairys You'd simply put colspan="3" inside your td:

`.prepend('<td colspan="3">'+$('#text1').text()+'</td>');`

Comment: Guys thanks for you help here, I got it all done thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add div value inside the created td:

This code:

```
$('#tablediv tr:eq(3)').prepend('<td></td>');
```

inserts a row - it looks like this is working for you.

To insert the content of `text1`, you could do:

```
$('#tablediv tr:eq(3)').prepend('<td>' + $("#text1").html() + '</td>');
```

---

A possible alternative would be to use `prependTo`, which returns the content that was prepended, eg:

```
var cell = $("<td></td>").prependTo($("table tr:eq(3)"));
cell.html($("#text1").html());
```

which can be shortened to:

```
$("<td></td>")
    .prependTo($("table tr:eq(3)"));
    .html($("#text1").html());
```

which uses chaining (using the return result of a call to make another call) and is more "jquery-esq" rather than concatenating strings which can become very messy very quickly.